# /proc/<pid>status SigIGN field

Tags: linux, signals

Is there any URL where I can get some information about `/proc/<pid>/status`. Especially the following fields:

```
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
```

Or can someone give some pointer to it?.

Answer (score 9):

Man `proc(5)` documents all of these entries.

From the manpage on my system, which is more comprehensive than some [online](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) versions I've seen ([this one's better](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)):

> - SigPnd, ShdPnd: Number of signals pending for thread and for process as a whole (see pthreads(7) and signal(7)).
> - SigBlk, SigIgn, SigCgt: Masks indicating signals being blocked, ignored, and caught (see signal(7)).
>     ockquote

Essentially they're counts and bitmasks of the signals which are waiting to be delivered (i.e. have been sent, but not received) to the process or thread in question and the signals which are being blocked/ignored/delivered.

Answer (score 3):

To decode the bit list of signals, I am using:

```
[mvutcovi@mvutcovi-lap2 ~]$ cat signals.sh 
#read -p "PID=" pid
pid=$1
cat /proc/$pid/status|egrep '(Sig|Shd)(Pnd|Blk|Ign|Cgt)'|while read name mask;do
    bin=$(echo "ibase=16; obase=2; ${mask^^*}"|bc)
    echo -n "$name $mask $bin "
    i=1
    while [[ $bin -ne 0 ]];do
        if [[ ${bin:(-1)} -eq 1 ]];then
            kill -l $i | tr '\n' ' '
        fi
        bin=${bin::-1}
        set $((i++))
    done
    echo
done
# vim:et:sw=4:ts=4:sts=4:
```